# Filter or Hide excess attachments in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, attachments

I have a client who has several "attachments" on all of their emails. These same attachments are included in every email and I would like to get rid of them or hide them anyway possible. Has anybody experienced this before and figured out how to de-clutter these emails? I'm thinking maybe a macro could do the trick but am not too versed in VBA... Also, what causes these files to be attached, specifically the `.htm` files? Thanks!

Below is a screenshot of the "attachments" I am referring to. Notice how they are random `.htm` files and the clients social media icons that are a part of their signature.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've done some more research and found this article. Looks like I'm out of luck on this one...

http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187